# Ordenar uma lista de alunos por nome em ordem alfabética

Tags: c

Isso foi o que eu pensei:

```
Aluno *ordenarNome(Aluno *aluno){
    Aluno *aux;
    Aluno *aux2 = (Aluno*)malloc(sizeof(Aluno));
    Aluno *aux3 = (Aluno*)malloc(sizeof(Aluno));
    Aluno *aux4 = (Aluno*)malloc(sizeof(Aluno));
    Aluno *aux5 = (Aluno*)malloc(sizeof(Aluno));
    *aux = *aluno;
    char nome[30];
    int id = 0;
    int matricula;
    int idade;
    while(aux != NULL){
        *aux2 = *aux->prox;
        while(aux2 != NULL){
            if(aux2->nome[0] < aux->nome[0]){
                *aux3 = *aux2;
                id++;
            }
                aux2=aux2->prox;
        }
        if(id > 0){
            *aux4 = *aux;
            *aux = *aux3;
            while(aux4 != NULL){
                aux->prox=aux4;
                aux5 = aux4->prox;
                if(aux3->id == aux5->id){
                    break;
                }
                aux4=aux4->prox;
            }
        }
        id=0;
    aux=aux->prox;
    }
    aluno = aux;
    return aluno;
}
```

Mas está dando falha (OBS: compilo usando gcc no linux e dá aquele erro de memória)

Comment: Por favor, náo coloque tags que nao tem nada a ver com o problema.

Comment: Prog verifica esse *aux2 = *aux->prox; que possivelmente está botando no lugar errado ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentou usar a função strcmp() da biblioteca string.h ?

A função strcmp() recebe duas string para ser comparadas entre si. O resultado pode ter 3 possíveis retornos:

**Menor que 0**: Carácter da primeira String for menor que da segunda String.

**Igual a 0:** Quando são iguais.

**Maior que 0:**  Quando o carácter da primeira String for maior (código ASCII) que da segunda String.

***Sintaxe:***

**strcmp** (*string1, string2*);

*Pequena demonstração:*

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>//necessário para strcmp
  #include <conio.h>
   int main ()
  {
  char str1[3] = "abc";
  char str2[3] = "abd";
   int retorno;

    retorno = strcmp(str1, str2);
    printf("retorno = %d\n", retorno);
     //mostra o retorno da função strcmp

     getch();
     return 0;
     }
```

Comment: ta dando erro e nao consigo alterar os valores sem perder outros, nao sei como implemtar essa troca, todos os valores sao perdidos nisso ai.

Comment: Aluno *aux2 = (Aluno*)malloc(sizeof(Aluno));  não teria como fazer isso na função main?  Cada vez que tu faz isso é como se estivesse criando um "nodo novamente zerado" . Faz isso no main, passa por parâmetro todas elas e depois compara.

Comment: deu certo aqui amigo, muito obrigado